# tortoise SVN - getting project from SVN repository and checking in from local

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

I want to get project from the trunk of SVN repositoy. Once that is done any changes that i make in local I should update to SVN. How can i do it?

I tried the following in tortoise SVN:

```
1. created a project folder.
2. right click and gave export option and the link for SVN repository. then ok
3. got all files to the local file system.
```

It works well. But i dont see the green tick mark in all the folders or I dont see SVN update or commit option when I right click my project folder. Why is it so? where am i wrong?

Comment: You are definitely doing it wrong since you didn't check the manual. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a folder in your local system.
2. Right click and select SVN check out.
3. Select the SVN repository you want to get.
4. Once you are done editing, right click and select SVN Commit.

Comment: I dont see the SVN copmmit option after I make change to the files. I dont see the green check mark at all.